# Trying to control DC motor speed with PID

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, pid

i'm trying to control a DC motor with PID. I have already made a code where i control the motor with an ultrasonic sensor (for distance) but now i need to run the motor at a given RPM (the Output). I did a lot of resarch and found that i will have to use the PID Library. But with my existing code i'm not sure if it's going to work. I know that i will have to modify PWM values by the Input on the analogWrite(). Can you enlight me on this PID? Here is my code:

```
int enableBridgePin = 10; 
int forwardPin = 11;
int backWardPin = 9;
int tickPin = 2;
const int trig = 5;
const int echo = 6;

int dt;
int distance;

void setup() {
  pinMode(enableBridgePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(forwardPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backWardPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  digitalWrite(forwardPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(backWardPin, LOW);

  digitalWrite(enableBridgePin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(enableBridgePin,255);

  digitalWrite(forwardPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(backWardPin, LOW);
  Serial.println(distancefonction(dt,distance));

  if (distancefonction(dt,distance)<15 && distancefonction(dt,distance)>7){
    slowdown();}
}

int distancefonction(int dt, int distance) //function to show distance

void slowdown(){
  for(int i=255;i>=0;--i){
      analogWrite(enableBridgePin,i);
      delay(10);}
   Serial.println("SLOWDOWN");
}
```

Comment: PID is a feedback loop control. So you first need feedback from the motor, e.g. some way to measure the actual speed/RPM of the motor. Only then you can use PID.

Comment: Does your  PWM `analogWrite(enableBridgePin,i);` work as desired ?  ( A minimal but complete and compilable code is appreciated :)

Comment: @chrisl the motor returns the tickPin

Comment: @DataFiddler yes the pwm works properly i tried it.

Comment: What does the motor with trickPin? You haven't explained this, nor do I see anything in your code. Are you already reading the current RPM back from the motor, or is this be actual problem?

Comment: @chrisl I can't read RPM on the motor. The tickPin is actually a timer pin connected to channel A (motor with encoder), i think everytime there is an impulsion the timer increments (i'm not sure abt that)

Comment: Is the "tickPin" a tachometer signal?

Answer (score 1):

PID- or any similar control needs

- set point
- actual value
- controlling variable (your PWM value)

The difference between set point and actual variable and its change over time are combined to calculate the controlling variable in order to minimize that difference.

Control theory in general is too complex to answer the "how to" here in general.

Besides measuring the actual value you also need knowledge about the behavior of your system: e.g. If you change the PWM value from 50 to 100, how much and how quick will the motor speed change? Even the response form over time will affect the optimal parameters for your control loop. It's called (feedback) loop because any change of the PWM value will change that difference and lead to a different new value of the controlling PWM value again (Allowing for instable behavior in case of bad controlling parameters).

Getting the actual value is your first task. How your `distancefonction` affects the desired value (set point) might also need more clarification...

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually 'distancefonction' just displays the distance between the object and the sensor. what i don't understand is how i'll get the actual value? the setpoint is 100rpm

Comment: One of the simpler ways is a optical wheel, or even just a small 'flag', attached the motor shaft, that interrupts a light beam every revolution (or part of one). Time the pulses and convert to RPM.